# JS - Returning Values That Match an ID

Tags: c#, javascript, json, database, unity-game-engine

I'm retrieving a character list from a database, which requires javascript to work (the rest of the script is in C#) as it is uLink's implementation of JSON within Unity3D. I need to basically say only return the values that match the account owner's ID (the character's have that ID stored on them).

This is what I have so far, it returns the entire character list and not ones specific to the account.

```
private const string GetCharacterListMapFunction =
    @"
function(value, keydata, arg) {
    var characterEntry = JSON.parse(value.values[0].data);
    return [characterEntry];
}
";

private const string GetCharacterListReduceFunction =
    @"
function(valueList, keydata, arg) {
    return valueList;
}
";
```

**this is how I call it**

```
private IEnumerator GetInfo()
{
    var bucket = new Bucket(bucketName);
    var getCharacterListRequest = bucket.MapReduce(new JavaScriptMapPhase(GetCharacterListMapFunction),
                                                new JavaScriptReducePhase(GetCharacterListReduceFunction));

    yield return getCharacterListRequest.WaitUntilDone();
    _characterEntries = getCharacterListRequest.GetResult<CharacterEntry>();
}
```

The dilemma here is I code in C# and don't know how to integrate the two because it'd have to check the ID of a C# string against the ID of the items in valueList (correct me if I'm wrong), I struggled to get even that working since I don't know JS. How can I re-write the code to do what I need it to do? I suppose I have no choice but to familiarize myself with JS, but a little help on this would be nice so I can at least finish up what I'm working on.